# Angular : how to declare object.property in ngModel dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, asp.net-mvc-4, angular4-forms

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Emp."+"dt.Rows[0]["columnname"]">
```

this give

> undefined

I'm using `MVC CustomHtmlHelper` to create `textbox(Because we need to create a dynamic form basis on the database)`,the control get render perfectly but "Emp.Name" is getting undefined.

Since the object is declare in TS.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Name" >
```

This work fine

I want to know how can we dynamically define object and its property. 
I'm using `angular 2` and `MVC5`.

Comment: What is your variable name in the end ?

Comment: [(ngModel)]="Emp.Name"

Answer (score 1):

**Emp.name** can be written as **Emp['Name']**. Try,

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Emp[dt.Rows[0]['columnname']]">
```

Comment: `"columnname"` should be replaced with `'columnname'`.

Comment: but on click i want to access Emp. say like <button (click)="save(Emp)" /> so that i can access/get all the property that are with Emp. (that the reason i'm passing [(ngModel)]="Emp."+"SomeDynamicText")

Comment: `but yes the Emp is not declare as object in TS,i'm just randomly attaching "Emp." with it the column name.`
So how you want bind undefined object to ngModel?

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="['Emp' + dt.Rows[0][columnname]]">
```

If your have declared the correct variables, such as

```
dt = {Rows: [{ name: John }]};
columnname = 'name';
```

Then you will have

```
[(ngModel)]="EmpJohn"
```

Comment: but on `click` i want to access Emp. say like <button (click)="save(Emp)" /> so that i can access/get all the property that are with Emp. (that the reason i'm passing [(ngModel)]="Emp."+"SomeDynamicText")

Comment: I asked you what your final variable is. You ask a question with no context, you get an answer out of your context. Give some context, and I will answer you.

Comment: My Final variable is "Emp.Name","Emp.DOB" but yes the Emp is not declare as object in TS,i'm just randomly attaching "Emp." with it the column name from DB,thats the reason my getting DOB,Name is undefined

Comment: And we agree that `Emp` is an object in your component, that contains a `Name` property, right ?

Comment: No i don't have any variable name Emp in my component,since i don't know how much property will be created by the user in DB.i'm asking if it is possible to declare [(ngModel)]="Emp.Name" even if Emp is not present in component.

Comment: If it's not present in the component, then what it will be bound to ?

Comment: Don't you have something like an object in your component, that contains the employee ?

Comment: No i don't have any object in component.

Comment: Then no, you can't bind to a property if you don't have a property. That is so obvious that I can't find words to explain it. That's like, wanting to put your meal on the table, except that you have no table.